# Excel VBA code to return multiple and unique vlookup values for duplicate lookup values

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with 3 worksheets: (1) Report, (2) category-1 and (3) category-2.

"Report" worksheet contains summary information of category-1 and category-2 data with unique ID of each category and grouping values. [See attached example image](http://screencast.com/t/ZtRzHpxGbCx).

I need to copy unique value from "Category1SubId" column of "Category1" worksheet to "Report" worksheet in "column-D" and then copy relevant value of "Category1Value" from "Category1" worksheet into "Report" worksheet in "Column-E".

For example, formula / VBA code to copy values from 1,2,3,4,5 for Apple into "Report" worksheet from "Category1" worksheet, and then copy "Breakfast" value for combination of "Apple and 1" into cell-E2 of Report worksheet from Category-1 worksheet and so on.

I tried combination of INDEX, VLOOKUP, ROWS and SEARCH formulas but none of them helped. I also tried VBA code to do it, but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help to solve this puzzle either through formula or VBA code?

Example of this worksheet is [attached here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pqkboh854uh1vf/Example%20of%20VLOOKUP%20Issue.xlsx?dl=0).

I tried following VBA code

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim category1LookupValueRange As Range
Dim category2LookupValueRange As Range

Dim category1SourceRange As Range
Dim category2SourceRange As Range

Dim category1TargetRange As Range
Dim category2TargetRange As Range

Dim targetValue As String

Set category1LookupValueRange = Worksheets("Report").Range("C2:C30")
Set category2LookupValueRange = Worksheets("Report").Range("F2:F30")

Set category1SourceRange = Worksheets("Category1").Range("A2:C30")
Set category2SourceRange = Worksheets("Category2").Range("A2:C30")

Set category1TargetRange = Worksheets("Report").Range("D2:E30")
Set category2TargetRange = Worksheets("Report").Range("G2:H30")

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim category1LookupValue As Object
Dim category1Id As Object
Dim category1IdValue As Object

Dim category2LookupValue As Object
Dim category2Id As Object
Dim category2IdValue As Object

For iRow = 1 To category1LookupValueRange.Count

Set category1LookupValue = category1LookupValueRange.Cells(iRow, 1)
Set category2LookupValue = category2LookupValueRange.Cells(iRow, 1)

Set category1Id = category1SourceRange.Range.Cells(category1SourceRange.Find(category1LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole), 1)
Set category2Id = category2SourceRange.Range.Cells(category2SourceRange.Find(category2LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole), 1)

Set category1IdValue = category1SourceRange.Range.Cells(category1SourceRange.Find(category1LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole), 1)
Set category2IdValue = category2SourceRange.Range.Cells(category2SourceRange.Find(category2LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole), 1)


If Not (category1LookupValue Is Nothing) Then
    If (category1SourceRange.Cells(iRow, 1) = category1LookupValue) Then

        Set category1TargetRange.Range.Cells(iRow, 1) = category1Id
        Set category2TargetRange.Range.Cells(iRow, 1) = category2Id

   End If
End If

Next iRow
```

Following array formula in Cell range D2 to D30 in Report worksheet

{=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($C2,Category1!$A$2:$A$30)),FALSE,TRUE),ROW(Category1!$B$1:$B$30)),ROW(Category1!$B$1:$B$30))),"",INDEX(Category1!$A$2:$C$100,SMALL(IF(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($C2,Category1!$A$1:$A$30)),FALSE,TRUE),ROW(Category1!$B$1:$B$30)),ROW(Category1!$B$1:$B$100)),1))}

Comment: data in columns 'Category1' and 'Category2' is in the same sequence as in sheets 'Category1' and 'Category2'. Will you be changing the sequence in any case?

Comment: You write * copy unique value from "Category1SubId"* but **ALL** of the SubID entries are unique. You should be aware that this is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I apologies for not showing proof that I have tried formula and VBA code to solve problem. Please refer to edited question with proof of my attempts. I also understand this place is not for free code-writing service. I have asked for help to resolve my problem.

Comment: Seeing code & examples often helps clarify the problem and leads to more focused advice.  In this case, it seems you could produce your report by merely pasting the columns from the other two worksheets into the report worksheet in the appropriate columns. What am I missing?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - If it was only once-off - I would certainly copy and paste values between worksheet and get moving. This is an example spreadsheet. I will get new data every week with various number of rows (records). I need to have smart Report tab and formulas/ Working VBA code which I can re-use to copy vlookup values from Category1 and Category2 spreadsheet for new data. Thus, I am trying to solve this problem by either formula / VBA code.

Comment: @AdityaPansare - Sequence will be changed in columns "Category1" and "Category2" in Report worksheet and in "Category1" and "Category2" worksheets.